# Why isn't std::variant allowed to equal compare with one of its alternative types?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

For example, it should be very helpful to equal compare a `std::variant<T1, T2>` with a `T1` or `T2`. So far we can only compare with the same variant type.

Comment: I think c++20 just added it to the draft with the [mothership proposal](https://brevzin.github.io/cpp_proposals/118x_spaceship/p1614r0.html#was-ill-formed-now-well-formed)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot In that same link, I believe it's saying the int would be implicitly cast to `std::variant<int, std::string>` to satisfy the comparison function signature. For an int, that's probably trivial. But for a string, that could mean a copy.

Comment: Shouldn't the compare also work in C++17? the operator== is a freestanding function. And variant has a non-explicit conversion-constructor, so variant<T1, T2>() == T1() should convert T1 to variant<T1, T2> and it shuould find the freestanding operator==. Actually after a check I found out that it does not work. Why is that so?

Comment: Actually following code works:
struct X {
    template<class T>
    X(T&&) {}
};
bool operator==(X const&, X const&);
X x(10);
bool b = x==10;

So it seemes to be related to operator== being a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an arbitrary decision by the standards committee.

Ok, not *quite* arbitrary. The point is you have a scale<sup>*</sup> of strictness of comparison, with points such as:

- Most-strict: Only variants can equal each other, and they need to match both in the sequence-of-alternatives (i.e. the type), the actual alternative (the index, really, since you can have multiple identical-type alternatives) and in value.
- Less-Strict: Equality of both the variant alternative, as a type and the value, but not of the sequence-of-alternatives, nor the index within that sequence (so the same value within two distinct alternatives of the same type would be equal).
- Most-relaxed: Equality of the value in the active alternative, with implicit conversion of one of the elements if relevant.

These are all valid choices. the C++ committee made the decision based on all sorts of extrinsic criteria. Try looking up the `std::variant` proposal, as perhaps it says what these criteria are.

<sub>(*) - A lattice actually.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

A variant may have multiple duplicates of the same type. E.g. `std::variant<int, int>`.

A given instance of `std::variant` compares equal to another if and only if they hold the same variant alternative and said alternatives' values compare equal.

Thus, a `std::variant<int, int>` with `index()` 0 compares not equal to a `std::variant<int, int>` with `index()` 1, despite the active variant alternatives being of the same type and same value.

Because of this, a generic "compare to `T`" was not implemented by the standard. However, you are free to design your own overload of the comparison operators using the other helper utilities in the `<variant>` header (e.g. `std::holds_alternative` and `std::get<T>`).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's just a statement of the situation. You did not say _why_ "a given instance of std::variant compares equal to another if and only if etc. etc."

Comment: When comparing an `int` with `std::variant<int, int>` it could compare the _active_ member with that `int`.

Comment: @einpoklum The standard just decided it should be that way. I'm explaining the reason (in terms of how the comparison operators work in the standard) for why a generic comparison to `T` is not in the standard.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You may want it to be like that, but that's not what the standard decided.

Comment: @CruzJean Well, in variant visitor you cannot distinguish between the two now - the comparison can be just as oblivious. I am not sure what use case the standard had in mind, however, one can wrap an integer into a unique class and get more mileage out of that.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but the standard libraries get outdated by the time they are integrated into the standard and then just code rot in there because standard library updates are almost non-existent. IMO, the standard commitee had better focus on modules, build and packaging system, so that people can pick and match libraries as they please.

Comment: `boost::variant` has been available for decades, excluding _i can't use boost_ people. Integrating `boost::variant` into `std` wouldn't be necessary if C++ had a package repository and a build system. Brain dump completed.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `boost::variant` also does not support equality-comparison with one of the alternative types.

Comment: @Barry True, i am not claiming otherwise. May be you could shed some light why variant supports duplicate types. Because if it didn't one could just do `myvariant == static_cast<decltype(myvariant)>(myint)` to compare. What was the more useful use case to allow duplicate types?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Because it's useful to model two different states that nevertheless have the same type.

Comment: @Barry One can always make 2 unique types from 1 type with a wrapper. IMO, that reason is not good enough.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Because `variant<a,b,c>` *always has* alternative 1 being `b`, and if alternative of var1 is not alternative of var2 they are never equal.  If you go down the path of "well, I'm sure they meant `variant<int, double>` when they said `variant<int, int, double>`", you end up with javascript `"1"==1` insanity.  If you want to go further, look up "sum types" in type theory.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Could not understand your logic, sorry.

Comment: What about an operator== between variant and T which only participates in overload resolution if T is one of the alternative types and the alternative types in the variant are unique?

Comment: @Kilian I like that, and that's personally how I'd have done it - nice and easy impl too. Just needs an `index()` check plus a template visitor. The `index()` check just being to make sure `std::variant<A, B>` holding `A` which is comparable to `B` still fails (so as not to fly in the face of the default comparison of two variants).

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer the *why* part of the question but since you think it would be useful to be able to compare a `std::variant<T1, T2>` with a `T1` or `T2`, perhaps this can help:

```
template<typename T, class... Types>
inline bool operator==(const T& t, const std::variant<Types...>& v) {
    const T* c = std::get_if<T>(&v);

    return c && *c == t; // true if v contains a T that compares equal to t
}

template<typename T, class... Types>
inline bool operator==(const std::variant<Types...>& v, const T& t) {
    return t == v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write this yourself! If you aren't so inclined to override equals operators (which in my opinion you shouldn't do with `std` classes), we can write with templates and `type_traits` the desired functionality.

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

template<class Variant, class T>
struct compare_variant;

template<class T, class ... Ts>
struct compare_variant<std::variant<Ts...>, T>
{
    static bool apply(std::variant<Ts...> obj1, T obj2)
    {
        return ((std::is_same<Ts, T>::value 
                && std::holds_alternative<T>(obj1) 
                && obj1 == obj2)||...);
    }
};
```

Note that this will only work if `T` is a member of `Ts...`. It is certainly possible to solve this for any arbitrary `T` but it requires slightly more complicated template machinery. Let me know if you would like this snippet as well.